# Connect from MySQL client in one container to MySQL server in other container of same pod

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I run two containers in a pod: one is based on `debian:wheezy`, the other one is `mysql:5.6`.

When I log into the 2nd container, I can invoke the MySQL client `mysql` without problems.

When I log into the 1st container and invoke the MySQL client `mysql` (after `apt-get install -y mysql-client`), I get this error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): 
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I assume this is because the two containers use their own file systems, and the socket exists only in the 2nd one's.

Is there a simple way for getting the MySQL client to work in the 1st container while the MySQL server runs in the 2nd and still using sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution consists of invoking the MySQL client in the 2nd container like this:

```
mysql -host 127.0.0.1
```

This will [force](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html) the client to make a TCP/IP connection instead of using a Unix socket file. (`localhost` would not do in this case.)